# Does incoming message auto truncated in .NET UdpClient/UDPServer?

Tags: .net, vb.net, udpclient

When working in VB6, i used Winsock  to send and receive message over internet.
The popular problem in VB6 Winsock is when i send a large string about 7000 character, the client received many part truncated to 2500->3000 character and i need to join truncated packet to have the original message like this:

```
Public FullMessage as string
Private Sub wskConnect_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim sBuff As String
    wskConnect.GetData sBuff, vbString
    FullMessage = FullMessage & sBuff
End sub
```

This problem is confirmed for VB6 winsock in this link ([VB6 Asynchronous Tcp Client truncates incoming messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609766/vb6-asynchronous-tcp-client-truncates-incoming-messages))

Now i'm going to migrate my code to .NET Framework.  Do i need to do the same method when working with .Net UDPClient/TCPClient ? Does .Net auto-resolve this problem for me or the message is still auto-truncated and i need to join it myself ? Does this problem come for both UDP protocol and TCP protocol or only for TCP protocol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i'm going to migrate my code to .NET Framework. Do i need to do the same method when working with .Net `UDPClient`/`TCPClient` ? Does .Net auto-resolve this problem for me or the message is still auto-truncated and i need to join it myself ? Does this problem come for both UDP protocol and TCP protocol or only for TCP protocol ?

TCP is a stream based protocol. In it there are no notation of messages (as in application level messages). It sees everything sent as bytes of data.

UDP on the other hand do promise that what you send is what you will receive.

However, there is another major difference. TCP guarantees that it will do the best o deliver your message (or die trying). UDP do not guarantee that. It just promises that if it would deliver your message it would be complete. But the message can get lost too.

So if you use TCP you'll get your data, but you have to assemble your messages by yourself. If you use UDP you'll get the messages the way you sent them. But the messages can be lost too.

imho it's much easier to assemble messages in TCP than writing a reliable protocol on top of UDP.

Comment: Your answer implies you can send just *any message* using UDP. Sending something greater than a single packet size will have the same problems as any stream-based protocol because you will need to implement a stream yourself. That's even more work than using TCP directly. Maybe you can edit that in before the OP decides that UDP will end all his problems of message sending.

Comment: In this case the 65k limit is enough as he stated `i send a large string about 7000 character`. However, i should have pointed that out just like you say.

Comment: thank you very much both men, i already tested myself and found the answer. I already know about the 65k limit, and the probability of packet lost while using UDP. The answer of jgauffin is fine for me. Also thank you so much @nvoigt for sharing a lot of helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no message truncation and there never was. The highest voted answer on your link even says so. This is how sockets *work*. They don't know anything about messages. They know that bytes are comming in. It's your job to handle messages.

`.NET` sockets work like sockets in other languages because that is how they were defined. However, if you want messages to be exchanged and don't care for the low level work of sockets, you can use mechanisms like `WCF` to have the `.NET Framework` do the heavy lifting and only deliver complete messages to you. This means that you have to give some control over how messages look to the `.NET Framework`. For `WCF` for example, that would be the `SOAP` specification or maybe even `REST`.

Comment: You might want to clarify that your answer is for stream based protocols like TCP and not for message based protocols like UDP.

Comment: @jgauffin did you mean that if i migrate to UDP so i don't need to join available packet like that ?

Comment: @user4835: Read my answer.

Comment: @jgauffin actually I would name UDP packet-based. The message may or may not fit in a single packet, so the user may receive more than one UDP message and will need to do the same (even more, due to loss and/or ordering) work as if it was sent by TCP.

Comment: In that case you are the only one saying that it's packet based ;) UDP is most often chosen to get rid of the header overhead for small packages, which means that the size do not matter.